# How can I add a new argument to the existing variable argument list?

Tags: c, multithreading, variadic-functions

In a multi-threaded program I'm writing a custom print function which accepts a variable argument list.

```
void t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, str);

            vfprintf(file_ptr, str, ap);

            va_end(ap);

            fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

Inside this function I want to add the *current thread id* (using `pthread_self()`) to the message getting printed. How can I do it? Is there a way to add it to the existing va_list?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just call `fprintf(file_ptr, format, pthread_self())` right before `vfprintf`?

Comment: @user786653 I just don't want to write pthread_self() always in the code. This function will get called frequently :)

Comment: Tangential to your question, but take a look at the [`format`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bformat_007d-function-attribute-2431) function attribute for a way to get type checking for `printf`-like functions (if you're using GCC).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### With a variadic macro:

With a variadic macro you can call the function with an argument prepended or appended:

```
#define t_printf(format, args...) \
    _t_printf(format, thread_id, __VA_ARGS__);
```

This prepends the `thread_id` before other arguments. (Note that on the `_t_printf()` function you have to modify the format string too.)

If you do this:

```
t_printf("some format string", a, b, c);
```

This will expand do this:

```
_t_printf("some format string", thread_id, a, b, c);
```

If `t_printf()` is called without other argument that format, you will have a trailing comma. GCC has a `##` extension that takes care of adding the comma as needed:

```
#define t_printf(format, args...) \
    _t_printf(format, thread_id ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Complete solution with the macro:

```
#define t_printf(format, args...) \
    _t_printf(format, thread_id, __VA_ARGS__);

void _t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
            char format[1024];

            /* safely prefix the format string with [thread_id: %x] */
            snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%s%s", "[thread_id: %x] ", str);

            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, str);

            vfprintf(file_ptr, format, ap);

            va_end(ap);

            fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

---

#### Without modifying the arguments

An other solution is to do two printf()s:

```
vsnprintf(buffer, bufsize, str, ap);
vfprintf(file_ptr, "[thread_id: %x] %s", thread_id, buffer);
```

Complete solution:

```
void _t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
            char buffer[1024];

            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, str);

            vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), str, ap);
            vfprintf(file_ptr, "[thread_id: %x] %s", thread_id, buffer);

            va_end(ap);

            fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but throwing the thread_id in front means you also need to modify the format string. Also, do you not need to use `##__VA_ARGS` syntax in the macro?

Comment: argument `str` should be there in vsnprintf, isn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't `fprintf()` be used instead of `vfprintf()` in *Without modifying the arguments* block?

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's no standard way to manipulate a va_list.
The stdarg.h header defines macros to declare, initialize, copy, terminate lists and fetch an argument (discerning type is up to caller).

Here's the suggestion of an alternative to accomplish the same result:
Note that this imposes a limitation on the format of the string. Depending on what you want, it may not be a problem:

```
#define MAXLEN 256
void t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, str);
        char msg[MAXLEN];

        vsnprintf( msg , MAXLEN , str , ap ); /* msg is guaranteed 
                                               * to be NULL terminated
                                               */

        /* Now that we have the message printed into a string,
         * print the message, along with the thread_id into the
         * console
         */
        fprintf( file_ptr, "thread % 6d: %s", pthread_self() , msg );

        va_end(ap);

        fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `vsnprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been written if the buffer was big enough, if it is larger than `MAXLEN`, then you can `malloc` some memory big enough and `vsnprintf` again.

Comment: @Node: That's right. I posted a simple solution just to show the part related to the addition of the thread ID. Also adding the mechanism to validate if the size of the temporary string was enough would be out of scope. Also, it is usually simpler to just provide enough space for the temporary string, given we know, _a priori_ the usual maximum length of the messages being printed out.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple. Pass a modified format string to vfprintf:

```
void t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
            char fmt[MAXLEN];

            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, str);
            // amend format and insert thread id 
            snprintf(fmt, MAXLEN, "thread id: %d: %s", pthread_self(), str);
            vfprintf(file_ptr, fmt, ap);

            va_end(ap);

            fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't simpler at all. You still need to make two calls to *printf() functions.

Comment: Simpler than what?
Is simple measured in number of function calls? or the complexities surrounding those calls.. ?
I see my suggestion is close to others, but mine only needs space for the passed format string (+ thread id string), not the entire message.

Comment: You are using the format string and the argument list in diferent function calls. Although it works, it is not immediate to the coder that the format on the vfprintf() call was actually embedded in 'fmt' in the previous call. If we compare the benefit of having only enough storage to keep the format itself plus the thread ID versus keeping the format and arguments always together and following a linear sequence of steps, I prefer the later. Nevertheless in the end it comes to a matter of taste. Cheers.

Comment: Taste matters. However, I would argue (depending on the arguments) the difference may be significant. Say you have a format of "%s", and pass a 512 byte long string to it. The required size for appending the thread id would be around 509 bytes more for the version that prints the whole message into the buffer, instead of just the format. On a desktop/server computer this won't matter much; but if you're doing embedded development, this amount of wasted memory is unforgivable. But sure, slightly less expressive, perhaps. A simple comment should be able solve that :)

Comment: @Kaos explanation added

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think there's a supported way to print the value of `pthread_self` (ref: the existence of [`pthread_equal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_equal.html)), here I'm casting it to a `void*` and using "%p" - change as you see fit.

Since, unfortunately, you can't add to a `va_list` I'd normally do something like this:

```
void t_printf(char * str, ...)
{
    if(file_ptr != NULL)
    {
            va_list ap;
            va_start(ap, str);
#if defined(USING_THREADS) && defined(LOGGING)
            fprintf(file_ptr, "%p", (void*)pthread_self());
#endif
            vfprintf(file_ptr, str, ap);
            va_end(ap);
            fflush(file_ptr);
    }
}
```

Since you ruled that out in the comments I assume this is to keep the function general and only have selected programs print thread id. I give you the following monstrosity:

```
#define t_printf(format, ...) t_printf("%p: " format, (void*)pthread_self(), __VA_ARGS__)
```

It only works if the format string is a literal and I don't recommend using it in production code, but it's an easy "hack" to get the job done.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Since `pthread_t` is an opaque there is no portable way to print it in a readable format. Now I generate a custom thread id and retrieve it in the `t_printf` function using `pthread_getspecific()`

Comment: I wonder what would be the performance hit of writing to a file twice, rather than using a buffer (via `vsnprintf` ) and then writing just once?

Comment: @Dulanja: Negligeble compared to the time it takes to perform the actual disk/screen I/O. BTW, `FILE*` are almost always (except `stderr`) at least line buffered (`setvbuf(3)`), so there shouldn't be any need to buffer on your own.